# CSS Style switcher in JavaScript on an Asp .Net server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mobile, server-side

I am trying to create a mobile website and can do it with just CSS, but the server master pages MUST be in their current locations, I am planning to use a Javascript "Style Switcher" to change the stylesheets but most mobile browsers don't have java support, so is there a way using java (or any other "language" that is either supported by mobile phones or can be run server-side) to run server-side that can also stop some of the page elements from loading (for mobile bandwidth issues) and change a few lines of the master code?

I was thinking of using this (with some edits):
[How to Use JavaScript to Change a Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) Dynamically](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml)

I cannot use PHP as our hosting provider will not install it.

I do not have Asp .Net access (as a user) but do have FTP access.

Comment: javascript != java.. so go ahead and use javascript ;) when saying most mobile browsers I guess we are talking about Opera Mobile/Mini, Safari Mobile and the Android native one - all of them can handle js pretty good :) you can have a look at http://h4kr.com I am switching the layout via js - just test it with your mobile browsers

Comment: @Walialu could you please post a sample so I can get an idea of how to properly STOP the other elements from loading?

Comment: i will, but you have to post an example first, then I know which elements to hide/stop loading ;)

Comment: Well, I would be stopping a lot of stuff and it is too long for here, I am mainly talking about roughly 8 js files for the home slider, dropdown menus, etc., some images and the other stylesheets (which are: style.css, HHStyles.css and HHStylesCustom.css), if you could just "answer" with a sample of your code then that would be my answer and I would mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var isMobile = function() {
    var w = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var o = 900;
    if(w < o) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

and an init func

```
var init = function(){
  if(!isMobile()){
    // all your desktop stuff goes here
    var desktopcss = document.createElement('link');
    desktopcss.rel = 'stylesheet';desktopcss.type = 'text/css';
    desktopcss.href='/desktop.css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(desktopcss);
  }
  else{
    // all your mobile stuff goes here
    var mobilecss= document.createElement('link');
    mobilecss.rel = 'stylesheet';mobilecss.type = 'text/css';
    mobilecss.href='/mobile.css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(mobilecss);
  }
};
```

and keep in mind that if you set something to

```
display:none;
```

via css, it will not be **loaded** and it will not be displayed!

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS media queries to adjust width of site for device making the request.

Comment: Please take a look at: affinitysearch.com, as you can see just shrinking it would not work, I have the mobile version at: affinitysearch.com/mobile/ except that the aspx sections cannot be moved to the mobile directory or edited to match the mobile website as that will change the main website, what I am looking for is something like stackoverflow's mobile version being that you can look at a page and it will be viewed as a mobile website while still being located at the same URL, and then if you go to the same URL on your computer it will show normally.

Comment: Personally I think that "Responsive Web Design" never works for this reason, but if you can't have a separate site, then you don't have a choice.